# VBA Code for looping through slicer in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Whilst I'm ok with Excel and formulas, I struggle with VBA. Any help available will be massively appreciated.  I feel I'm almost there but not all the way.

I want to create a macro that loops through a slicer called "AM" which will then print to pdf and save in designated file path. The issue I have is although my code runs through to completion, my pdf files show a combination of the items, rather than a file for each item in the slicer.

A screenshot of the table format in use is attached to give an idea of what I'm working with

[image: Test Screenshot]

```
Sub PrintCategoryPDFs()
    
    Dim slc As Slicer
    Dim slcCache As SlicerCache
    Dim slcItem As SlicerItem
    
    Dim categoryName As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim filePath As String
    
    Dim weekNum As Long
    
    'Get the week number
     weekNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.weekNum(Date)
    
    'Set the file path - edit as necessary
    filePath = "C:\Users\pellowjones\Desktop\Reports\"
    
    'Get the slicer cache
    Set slcCache = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_AM")
    
    'Loop through the slicer's items
    For Each slcItem In slcCache.SlicerItems
        
        'Get the category name
        categoryName = slcItem.Name
        
        'Set the file name
        fileName = categoryName & " - Report " & weekNum & ".pdf"
        
        'Print the PDF
        slcCache.SlicerItems(categoryName).Selected = True
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=filePath & fileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
        
        'Deselect the slicer item
        slcCache.SlicerItems(categoryName).Selected = False
    
    Next slcItem
    
End Sub
```

I need the code to create a pdf for AM 1's data, AM 2's data etc, without effectively stacking the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the `'Print the PDF` comment line, add

```
Dim slcItem2 As SlicerItem
For Each slcItem2 In slcCache.SlicerItems
    slcCache.SlicerItems(slcItem2.Name).Selected = slcItem2.Name = categoryName
Next slcItem2
```

And then delete / comment-out the `slcCache.SlicerItems(categoryName).Selected = True` line (ie that immediately follows the `'Print the PDF` comment line)

Comment: It worked straight away! Thank you so much for taking the time to look at it!